# Parameterize an MySQL IN clause in Python code

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I was looking at this similar question: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)
But the solution is not using Python, so I had to raise a new question:
How do I parameterize a query containing an IN clause, the strings `'ruby','rails','scruffy','rubyonrails'` comes from a column of a dataframe

```
SELECT * FROM Tags 
WHERE Name IN ('ruby','rails','scruffy','rubyonrails')
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

The dataframe `df` might look like:

```
column1  column2...
ruby     .
rails    . 
scruffy  .
xxx
xxxx
```

Here's what I've tried:
I converted the first column to a list and name it `list`, then update the second line in the query:

```
WHERE Name IN %(list)s
```

But this gave me an error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where Name IN (('ruby','rails','xxx','xxxx','xxx','' at line 2")`

I also tried `list = str(list)[1:-1]` to remove the square bracket, but then I got error: `MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where Name IN ('\\'ruby\\', \\'rails\\', \\'xxxxx\\', \\'xxx\\',' at line 2")`

My question is what format/datatype I should use for `df[column1]` to get this working? Can someone help please? Thanks.

Comment: Update: I've resolved this, turns out I only need to convert it to a list (with the square bracket), no need to remove the bracket otherwise it won't work!

Answer (score 0):

The only answer here doesn't work, since I've resolved this, so here's the solution: turns out I only need to convert it to a list (with the square bracket), no need to remove the bracket otherwise it won't work!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can convert the column list to a tuple:

```
col_tuple = tuple(list)
```

Then use a python f-string in your query:

```
f"""SELECT * FROM Tags 
WHERE Name IN {col_tuple}
ORDER BY Count DESC"""
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm not sure if this works because in my query, I have a couple of other parameterized strings, like date etc, they are using the format `%(date)s` in the MySQL query.

Comment: I think that this is open to SQL injection attack, as input is not sanitized.